# How to run python in vs code with run code option

Tags: visual-studio

It's beyond the life of me,

But I have setup my python interpreter correctly in the settings and in my OS environment in VS code.  However, when i press play code or press command option N in vs code, I get a syntax error output in my code, which otherwise the syntax error is not there if i run the code in the terminal using something like "python3 filename.py".

Any advice here?  Thanks.

James

Comment: please post the complete error message you're getting in vs code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it - this was directly related to the CodeRunner extension.  A JSON setting had to be changed.  Specifically, I had to add an entry to point to the correct python interpreter.